# Regression says $H_1$ is accepted, One-Way ANOVA says $H_1$ is rejected. Are different results possible?

Tags: regression, anova

I am testing my hypotheses with a 2x2x2 between subjects design.
Thus I am testing the moderation effects on the dependent variable.

When I used regression to conduct this test, $H_1$ was accepted.
However when I used One- way- ANOVA to further test this, $H_1$ was rejected.

I am just wondering whether I have done something wrong, or is this normal?

Update:

Just to clarify my research has three moderating variables : Price, duration and Frequency and I am testing whether or not this has an moderating effect on consumer's enjoyment and attitude towards in app purchases. All questions are 7-point Likert scales.

Comment: We don't reject the alternative. We either reject or fail to reject the null. It's not clear how your two tests differed.

Comment: H1 = Duration has a moderation effect on enjoyment and attitude , such that the shorter the duration the stronger the relationship between them.

When I performed the multiple regression analysis it accepted H1 and proofed that there was a significant relationship between them.

However ANOVA says there is no support for this, thus H1 is not true. 

My question is: Can this be possible or do regression and ANOVA always have to provide the same conclusions?

Comment: Can you please indicate *exactly* which models you fitted and tested in each case.